# Block website from webbrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control

Is it possible to block websites in visual basic before the website actually loads.

For example:

If I try to load [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) and hit go it doesn't load the website but give an error message. I have tried searching but cannot find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 '
  '
Dim MyURL As String
  '
  '  
Private Sub Command1_Click()
 MyURL = "http://www.website.com"
 WebBrowser1.Navigate2 MyURL
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
 If Instr(URL, MyURL) > 0 Then
   Cancel = True ' Do not allow
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy thing you are asking. It looks like this. You basically hook into the Navigating Event which occurs before Navigation and any loading does. Then you can check the URL for whatever you want, and then either cancel navigation or re-route to an approved website.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
        If e.Url.ToString.Contains("www.badwebsite.com") Then
            e.Cancel = True
            'WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.goodwebsite.com")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```